# Formatting structured Kafka stream in pyspark using named regex

Tags: python, spark-structured-streaming, pyspark, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm trying to extract multiple columns values from an existing column in a streamable pyspark dataframe.

I read the stream using

```
stream_dataframe = spark_session.readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", broker) \
        .option("subscribe", topic) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .load()
```

I'm currently splitting the string in value column and applying a schema to that using,

```
assert sdf.isStreaming == True, "DataFrame doesn't receive streaming data"
# split attributes to nested array in one Column
col = split(sdf[col_name], split_str)
# now expand col to multiple top-level columns
for idx, field in enumerate(schema):
    sdf = sdf.withColumn(field.name, col.getItem(idx).cast(field.dataType))
return sdf
```

I wanted to use named regex instead of the above.

I tried using the below code,

```
host_pattern = r'(^\S+\.[\S+\.]+\S+)\s'
ts_pattern = r'\[(\d{2}\/\w{3}\/\d{4}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2} (\+|\-)\d{4})\]'
method = r'\s([A-Z]{3,7})\s'
# url = r'\s((\/((\w+\/*\?*.(\w))+)\s))'
url = r'\s(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/\S]+)'
protocol = r'\s([A-Z]+\/\d\.\d)\s'
status_pattern_size = r'\s(\d{3})\s(\d+)\s'
uuid_pattern = r'(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$)|(([0-9a-f]{32})$)'
df = df.selectExpr(regexp_extract('value', host_pattern, 1).alias('host'),
                   regexp_extract('value', ts_pattern, 1).alias('time'),
                   regexp_extract('value', method, 1).alias('http_method'),
                   regexp_extract('value', url, 1).alias('request_uri'),
                   regexp_extract('value', protocol, 1).alias('http_protocol'),
                   regexp_extract('value', status_pattern_size, 1).cast('integer').alias('response_status'),
                   regexp_extract('value', status_pattern_size, 2).cast('integer').alias('response_time'),
                   regexp_extract('value', uuid_pattern, 1).alias('instance_id'))
```

This throws me an error saying `Column is not iterable`.

I wanted to use the following name regex instead, as the above would lead to multiple regexp_extract calls,

```
(?P<host>\S+)\s+\S+\s+(?P<user>\S+)\s+\[(?P<time>.*?)\]\s+(?P<http_method>\S+)\s+(?P<request_uri>\S+)\s+(?P<http_protocol>\S+)\s+(?P<response_status>\S+)\s+(?P<reponse_time>\S+)\s+(?P<instance_id>\S+)
```

for extracting the values for the respective columns.
Is it possible to do that on a streamable pyspark dataframe?